# general way for using turtle graphics in ruby

Tags: ruby, turtle-graphics

Is there a general way to use turtle graphics in ruby like this?

```
require 'turtle'
Turtle.draw do
    pencolor blue
    forward 100
end
```

I tried hackety-hack, which is nice but too buggy (crashes almost every minute). I am also trying rdf-turtle, but I have no idea how to draw a single line. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [rdf-turtle](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf-turtle) is just a library for parsing the RDF format and not for drawing anything.

If you want to draw something with turtle in Ruby, checkout [Kidsruby](http://www.kidsruby.com/about). It comes with a GUI and a turtle module.